# Qt static build and link to icu libraries statically

Tags: linux, qt

I've built Qt 5.9.6 statically using these commands on Ubuntu 14.04

```
git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git
perl init-repository --module-subset=qtbase,qtimageformats,qtcharts,qtsvg,qttools,qttranslations,qtx11extras
git submodule foreach --recursive git checkout v5.9.6
./configure -prefix "/usr/local/Qt-5.9.6" -release -force-debug-info -opensource -confirm-license -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -qt-harfbuzz -qt-pcre -qt-xcb -qt-xkbcommon-x11 -no-opengl -static -openssl-linked -nomake examples -nomake tests
MAKE_THREADS_CNT=-j8
make $MAKE_THREADS_CNT
sudo make install
```

so the build goes ok and at the end i can add this build to my QtCreator and build a test project. The problem is that the end result executable is linked dynamically to these libraries:

- libicui18n.so.52
- libicuuc.so.52
- libicudata.so.52

and this is a problem which makes my executable app not run on other ubuntu systems. I want these libraries to be statically linked to my project.

these libraries are located at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and there are 2 versions of them a statically compiled(.a) and some dynamically compiled(.so) versions.

I've also noticed the command that QtCreator uses to link contains these libs:

```
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o test main.o   -L/usr/local/Qt-5.9.6/lib -lQt5Core -lm -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -lqtpcre2 -ldl -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lpthread
```

Should I change something in my build or should I change my `.pro` on my project to make these libraries link statically?